# How to increase the acceleration speed of IBM Touchpad and Trackpoint in Xubuntu 17.04?

Tags: xubuntu, thinkpad

How do I increase the acceleration speed of IBM Touchpad and Trackpoint in Xubuntu 17.04?

I'd also like to re-enable the Touchpad tap function.

None of the Mouse Options within the default UI seem to make any difference whatsoever using libinput (I presume).

Answer (score 2):

In a terminal, execute the following commands to show the available parameters than can be modified. You can test on the fly before committing.

```
~$ xinput list-props "TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint"
```

The above will list TrackPoint options.

```
~$ xinput list-props "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"
```

The above will list Touchpad options.

The following settings are the ones I settled on:

```
# IBM Trackpoint Acceleration Speed
xinput set-prop "TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint" "277" 1.0

# IBM Touchpad Enable Tapping
xinput set-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "295" 1

# IBM Touchpad Acceleration Speed
xinput set-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "277" 1.0
```

Simply place these in the following file, save and re-login:

```
/home/your-user-name/.xinputrc
```

Feel free to play with the variables until you find settings that fit your needs. I put everything on full-tilt, and it's still not quite enough, but it's a vast improvement - especially for the TrackPoint.

The numbers 277, 295 and 277 are the codes for the following functions:

```
Trackpoint (277) = libinput Accel Speed

Touchpad (295) = libinput Tapping Enabled

Touchpad (277) = libinput Accel Speed
```

You can verify your settings following re-login or reboot (if you prefer), but re-running:

```
~$ xinput list-props "TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint"
~$ xinput list-props "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that with Xubuntu 16.04 my settings set with Settings Editor or     with the Mouse and Pointers configurator GUI tool were being ignored for my TrackPoint ( the little red joystick thingy ).

Apparently by default the acceleration profile is set to 0 which is an invalid value.  https://www.x.org/wiki/Development/Documentation/PointerAcceleration/

I ended up setting it to 2 using this in my .xinputrc

```
# Acceleration profile polynomial.  Otherwise ignores settings.
xinput set-prop "TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint" 266 2
```

The number 266 comes from

```
$ xinput list-props "TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint"
```

It's the "Device Accel Profile" setting ( set to 0 by default )  Your number may vary so use the xinput list-props command to look it up.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your findings. I've pretty much dropped Xubuntu in favour of Budgie, which is both lightweight and works OOTB for me.